# CORS error during API call for React/DRF app on Heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, heroku, django-rest-framework

I have my react front end and my django rest api as two separate apps on heroku. I'm having the issue of the following error:

[image]

The request options I use for the fetch request on the frontend:

```
const credentials = btoa(`${data.get('username')}:${data.get('password')}`);
const requestOptionsSignIn = {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "Authorization": `Basic ${credentials}`
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({})

}
```

And my Django/django-cors-headers settings:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['https://_____frontend.herokuapp.com']
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ("x-requested-with", "content-type", "accept", "origin", "authorization", "x-csrftoken")
```

I've tried playing around with the settings but I can't get it to work.

Comment: I don't see anything in your server code that allows specific request methods. EG for CORS you normally have to whitelist the request methods as well `[:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]`

Comment: I added it but no difference

Comment: One more try. It could be a mixture of things but your error specifies that 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' must be a wildcard. In your `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS` you have set your domain. Have you tried not setting it, setting it to an empty array or have an array of `['*']`? CORS can be a pain.

Comment: It says must not be a wildcard, if I'm not mistaken. Regardless, I've tried with CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True which does what you mean I think.